# JavaScript - parseFloat force 2 decimals as NUMBER

Tags: javascript

I realize this has been asked in some shape or form plenty of times, but every answer I've read so far says use .toFixed(2), unfortunately, that returns the result as a **String**.

Some people suggested parsing twice, eg:

```
parseFloat(parseFloat("29.6").toFixed(2))
```

but that returns:

```
29.6
```

Is there a way to force parseFloat (or anything else!) to return a **NUMBER** type with 2 decimals?

Comment: An actual *number* won't have a trailing `0` in the decimal portion of its printed representation.

Comment: Why do you need 2 digits after decimal? It it needs to be displayed, `string` type is appropriate, if it needs to be used in computation, the zero is insignificant.

Comment: It's because `5.50000` is `5.5` if it's a number. If you want the `0` after then don't `parseFloat` the return value of `toFixed` which is a string (`"29.60"`).

Comment: I know that 5.5 and 5.50 are equal, but I needed to display (with zeros) and use as a number, I'm also aware of the javascript limitations but was hoping someone had a clever workaround so I can avoid displaying a string. It was a long shot :D.

Comment: @Mankind1023 What limitations?  This doesn't make any sense.  If you want to display something, it's going to be a string.  You can still keep the same number around.  If you're asking simply how to round a number, that's different.  Don't forget though that this is floating point land, and you might get surprised by something like 0.9999999999999 showing up instead of 1.000000000000.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
var your_value = 10.01 // replace with any value you desire
parseFloat(Math.round(your_value * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

Examples

```
var j = parseFloat(Math.round(29.6 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
console.log(j);
//Output = >"29.60"
var j = parseFloat(Math.round(30.2100 * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
console.log(j);
//Output =>"30.21"
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. You're creating a String while the OP wants a Number.

Comment: The OP has already stated `toFixed` doesn't do what they want. (JS doesn't do what they want either, which is what we're attempting to explain.)

Comment: I got it. Well then the question is little weird because whatsover we try 29.60 is basicaly 29.6 converted to numeric type. I am sorry I really did not read the Number part.

Comment: Yep, OP has a misconception about printed representation of numbers.