# How to make multiple Jquery events with nested if statements pretty

Tags: jquery

I am working on this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r0up5ks6/1/)

It is not 100% working, but very close. How I can improve this code, and achieve 100% ?

How it should work (there is 2 main scenarios):

1. When trading type is selected "Sale", Sales Stage 1 div is shown.

- When IsPaid is checked as PAID:

  - Payment Type (show/enabled/required)
  - Payment Sum (show/enabled/required)
  - Payment Done (show/enabled/required)
  - Payment Date (show/enabled/required)
  - S1 Note (show/enabled/optional)
  - S1 File (show/enabled/optional)
  - If Paydone < Paysum, then Payment Deadline is shown, enabled and required, else it is disabled and hidden. (Paysum is also calculated by jquery code as `parseInt(bid_q) * parseInt(bid_p)`
- When IsPaid is checked as NOT PAID::

  - Payment Deadline is shown, enabled and required
  - S1 Note is shown, enabled and optional

2. When trading type is selected "Bid", Sales Stage 1 div with its all inputs, selects disabled and hidden.

I think I am almost there, but i feel like if statements and jquery codes becomes a bit lengthy and if statements might be conflicting. I wonder I there is much pretty and efficient way without any redundant codes.

UPDATE-2: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r0up5ks6/2/)

UPDATE-3: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r0up5ks6/3/) (Payment Deadline required attr was added)

UPDATE-4: [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/r0up5ks6/4/) (Update based on comments)

SOME NOTES REGARDING COMMENTS:

- Disabling input fields matters as I use form submit. And I need make sure disabled fields are not posted into php.
- PayDone is not boolean, but integer. It is amount of payment done by client. Ex: if total order cost is 100 usd, and the client pays only 80. It means paydone is 80, paysum is 100.
- Pay Deadline Date. It should be required only when not paid or paydone < paysum.

Comment: On how to improve you code I would visit https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Second I would not advise you to bind events inside another event.

Comment: I'll second the statement about codereview but for my 2 cents, indentation is rule #1 of code cleanliness. Be consistent with indents, curly braces, etc. You can also reuse multiple lines of code that are largely the same by wrapping them inside a function (arrow or otherwise). A good example is lines 31-33, which you use 4 times, swapping a true and false. You could wrap that inside an inline arrow function with a single parameter and just call that function each time. Comments are also a good way to keep code clean and readable, and your fellow developers will thank you later for using them.

Comment: Going through your question, I haven't yet found the part that "isn't working." Please detail **exactly** what isn't working. While it's nice to have the spec, I don't want to spend several minutes testing the whole thing to find the problem. If you know that problem, put it in the question.

Comment: i have updated fiddle. It is now 100% working as i need. But i am still not sure if the code can be optimized and is there any redundancy. https://jsfiddle.net/r0up5ks6/2/

Comment: Some comments:  your `select` has only 2 options, so is tedious to use - use a radio as you have later on for ispaid.  This also keeps the UI consistent.   As noted above, you have a nested event, add a `console.log` inside #s1_status input click then switch the trading type a few times.   While it doesn't "matter" here as it does the same each time, over time you will run out of resource and each time it will take longer and longer.

Comment: Disabling a field will stop it from being POST'd.  It's unclear if that matters given the sample.  If you `.hide()` a field (or it's container), you don't need to disable it as it can't be focused to be changed.

Comment: Not sure what "Payment Done" should be, but by the caption, it should be a boolean, as in "your payment is done".  I'm guess this should be "Payment Made".   `$(document).on("keyup input", "#s1_paydone"` should also run on the other relevant fields, not just #paydone - eg if you enter paydone first, the change qty so paysum changes, your code doesn't run.  In that event handler you have unused variables, remove them if they're not used.

Comment: Biggest issue:  in the #s1_paydone event, paysum and paydone are strings, so if paysum = 10000 and paydone = 15, it thinks you've paid.  These **must be converted to numeric** - in biq_q/bid_price you force integers, so your unit price can't have decimals, which sounds unrealistic.

Comment: paydone is amount of payment done. Lets say, total order cost is 100 usd. And client only pays 80 usd now. This means paydone is 80, paysum is 100. And in php backend i do payleft=paysum-paydone and insert it to DB table as well.

Comment: Yes, clearly, but that's pretty bad grammar.

Comment: @freedomn-m "in biq_q/bid_price you force integers, so your unit price can't have decimals, which sounds unrealistic" what is proper way to do it. I need decimals as well actually.

Comment: You could use parseFloat() but generally "floats" are a bad idea. Most people recommend `paysum = +$("#s1_paysum").val();` or you can use `$("#s1_paysum").val() * 1` - you might like to [round](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43504311/2181514) this (ceil/floor) so you only have two decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

Concentrating on the partial/non payment issue I put together the following shorter snippet. The logic is condensend in the calculation of `flag`. It is true when the payment was not made or the partial payment is smaller than the expected amount.

```js
$(document).on("input", "#s1_paydone,[name=s1_status]", function() {
  var is_paid = $("#paid").is(":checked");
  var not_paid = $("#unpaid").is(":checked");
  var paysum = +$("#s1_paysum").val(); // + converts implicitly to number
  var paydone = +$("#s1_paydone").val();
  
  const flag = not_paid || (paydone < paysum);
  
  $("#s1_deadline").prop({ required: flag,  disabled: !flag });
  $(".s1_deadline").toggle(flag);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input type="radio" id="paid" name="s1_status" value="PAID" style="margin-top:10px;margin-right:10px" required="required"><label style="margin-right:30px" for="paid"> PAID</label>
<input type="radio" id="unpaid" name="s1_status" value="UNPAID" style="margin-top:10px;margin-right:10px"><label for="unpaid"> NOT PAID</label>
</div>
<div class="item form-group s1_paid_in">
  <label class="col-form-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 label-align" for="s1_paysum">Payment Sum (Total)</label>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <input id="s1_paysum" type="number" name="s1_paysum" class="form-control has-feedback-left" value="1234" step="any">
    <span id="fa_s1_target2" class="fa fa-money form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item form-group s1_paid_in">
  <label class="col-form-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 label-align" for="s1_paydone">Payment Done<span class="required">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <input id="s1_paydone" type="number" name="s1_paydone" class="form-control has-feedback-left" step="any" required="required">
    <span id="fa_s1_target" class="fa fa-money form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="s1_paydate" class="item form-group s1_paid_in" style="display:none">
  <label class="col-form-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 label-align" for="s1_paydate">Payment Date <span class="required">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <input class="form-control has-feedback-left" type="date" name="s1_paydate" value="" required="required" disabled="">
    <span class="fa fa-calendar form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item form-group s1_deadline" style="display:none">
  <label class="col-form-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 label-align" for="s1_paydeadline">Payment Deadline <span class="required" style="display:none">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <input id="s1_paydeadline" class="form-control has-feedback-left" type="date" name="s1_paydeadline" value=""> (For not paid case or not full payment processes)
    <span class="fa fa-calendar form-control-feedback left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```